# Grails 2.4.0 filters

Tags: grails

I have created a filter class and added CORS headers there. Restarted app (also tried clean, compile.. even restart eclipse) but my REST controllers are not setting these headers in responses. Any pointers on how to debug? May be I am doing some thing wrong but from the doc looks like that is all I need to do to add filters in Grails ([filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters))

```
class AddcorsheadersFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {

            }
            after = { Map model ->
                response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH')
                response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Additional-Headers-Example')
                response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
                response.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000')

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10806) this issue is well known won't be fixed at all.

> The respond method will render JSON which commits the response. It is too late at this point to add headers. Headers will need to be added in the 'before' block or in the action. Changing the index action to

As an alternative solution you could use the [BeforeIntercepter](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) and apply the headers to all actions in your controller.

The ticket is also very likely related to [Grails doesn't add headers for json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054153/grails-doesnt-add-headers-for-json)

Comment: Thanks. Added to 'before' and I can see the headers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong in a nutshell is that you are setting the headers after they are already set! the `after` block is called after processing is already done but before view is rendered. That means by the time the `after` block is called, the headers would have already been set (Am not sure but may be sent too)!

The solution is to set the headers before anything is processed! `before` block is called even before the controller is called, the processing begins there! Hence would be an ideal place to set the headers there!!!